# how can i scroll to specific line in a webforms TexetBox using c#

Tags: asp.net

I have a TextBox multiline and i need to scroll to specific line in textbox..
Please help me

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "check", "<script type=\'text/javascript\'>document.getElementById('" + this.textbox.ClientID + "').scrollHeight=100;</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using scrollTop?

e.g.

```
function scrollTextBox()
{
    var textBox = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
    textBox.scrollTop = 30;
}
```

You'll need to calculate the scrollTop value though using the line number.

Comment: Thkx for your reply but didn't work